# docx4j deployment on Resin

Tags: jaxb, moxy, docx4j, resin

I want to use docx4j to convert html files to docx files. I create a project in Eclipse and the conversion is ok, but when I try to integrate docx4j in our web application I have an error.
I use:
-   Docx4J v3.2.1
-   Java v1.6
-   Resin 2.1.0. 
I added all the dependencies jars in Build Path’s project.

The error is :

2014-11-10 10:33:10 ERROR: Cannot initialize context
com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 61 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
Two classes have the same XML type name "CT_TwipsMeasure". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
  this problem is related to the following location:
         at org.docx4j.wml.CTTwipsMeasure
        at protected org.docx4j.wml.CTTwipsMeasure org.docx4j.wml.CTFramesetSplitbar.w
……..
2014-11-10 10:33:17 ERROR:
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
 - with linked exception: [java.lang.NullPointerException]
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.unmarshal(JaxbXmlPartXPathAware.java:439)
 at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.StyleDefinitionsPart.unmarshalDefaultStyles(StyleDefinitionsPart.java:147)
 at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:416)
at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.createPackage(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:377)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at what JAXB implementation Resin is using.  Is it using an implementation included in Java, or some other?

If you can use the reference implementation (a recent version), do that.  Otherwise, you can add MOXy to your class path.  See further http://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/moxy-t1242.html

Comment: I added docx4j-MOXy-JAXBContext-3.0.0.jar to project  class path and eclipse persistence jars (org.eclipse.persistence.moxy-2.5.1.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.core-2.5.1.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.antlr-2.5.1.jar, org.eclipse.persistence.asm-2.5.1.jar), but I have the same Context problem.
‘2014-11-12 10:22:58 INFO : MOXy JAXB implementation intended..
2014-11-12 10:23:03 ERROR: Cannot initialize context
javax.xml.bind.JAXBException:
Exception Description: Name collision.  Two classes have the XML type with uri  and name CT_LongHexNumber.
….’.